# Keyboard hidden when EditText focused

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, hide, show

I have two fragments in one Activity and both of the fragments contain one EditText. When the the first EditText is focused (keyboard shown) and the user presses the next button of the keyboard, I am transferring the focus to the EditText in the second fragment by using this code:

```
View next = autoCompleteTextView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    if (next != null) {
        next.requestFocus();
    }
```

The second EditText receives the focus as it should (the cursor starts blinking in it) but the keyboard that was shown, gets hidden. 
I don't understand why this happens. I tried million different solutions, to force the keyboard to be shown again but nothing works. I don't know why it gets hidden in the first place, I am just transferring focus.

Comment: you have `focusable` set to `true` on EditText?

Comment: yes, i have focusable set to true

Comment: try showing and hiding keyboard programmatically when focus is changed..

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is this:

```
 mComposeMsgBody.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && mComposeMsgBody.isEnabled()) {

                mComposeMsgBody.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(mComposeMsgBody, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

But it is not ideal, since the keyboard tries to get hidden, and then I am forcing it go up, so there is this 1 second down-up movement that the keyboard does. If someone has a better solution for just transferring focus without the keyboard doing anything, please post an answer.